# Does android remove info logs on release builds?

Tags: android

When running my app on `debug` I get info logs. When running it on `release` mode I don't get them. I want to know if removing the logs is something I am doing without knowing it or if Android by default does that?

Thanks.

Edit: After some tests, I'm pretty sure my config is the one removing `info` logs on `release` builds but I don't know why. I don't have the removal stuff on my main proguard. I'm guessing some library maybe has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that an ad network had added this to their proguard config:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable logcat logging for Release build, add `debuggable true` to your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        ...
    }
}
```